# Single word for?

Tags: meaning

Please give me a single word for: *the ability of writing and speaking of a language.*

Answer (score 3):

I think yo ucan use "fluent" without specifying if it is written or spoken. For example: "I'm fluent in English"

Answer (score 0):

Some of these choices have already been suggested in the other answers. I going to suggest few additional words:

i)basic  ii) intermediate iii) professional working proficiency or business level iv) fluent. These words may be used to describe proficiency in each of the linguistic skill (writing, reading, speaking, listening).

You may also check out following resources:
i) https://academic.oup.com/applij/article-abstract/34/1/99/150948?redirectedFrom=PDF

ii) https://academic.oup.com/applij/article-abstract/34/1/99/150948?redirectedFrom=PDF

Answer (score -1):

I think 'linguistic proficiency' is the word you are looking for. Wikipedia defines it as "the ability of an individual to speak or perform in a language."